# .htaccess script to remove .php extension prevents index.php access

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use the following script to remove the `.php` extension when accessing my web pages. However, this prevents me from accessing the `index.php` of the website by simply going to the main website URL.

How can I fix this issue so that both `.php` extensions are removed, and I can access the `index.php` by just typing out the website name?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This rule doesn't actually do anything when you request the document root, ie. "the main website URL" because the regex `^([^\.]+)$` won't match. What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite This is all the script

Comment: To clarify, if you remove those 3 lines then you can access `index.php` by simply requesting the main website URL, eg. `https://example.com/`?

Comment: And what version of Apache are you using?

Comment: And what response are you actually getting when "going to the main website URL"? A 403, 404, 500, ...? Also, please clarify the URL you are requesting?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes when typing base URL `https://example.com` it redirects to index.php without htaccess script. I am not sure of Apache version, I am using the latest MAMP. I am receiving 404 when going to `https://example.com` after the htaccess script

Comment: Ok, there seems to be something a bit strange going on here... to debug this we need to see what URL the above rule is matching (it shouldn't be matching anything when requesting "the main website URL" only). To do this we can temporarily change the `RewriteRule` directive into a redirect (as opposed to a rewrite) and see what URL it redirects to. eg. `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [R,L]` - now when you request `https://example.com/`, what URL are you redirected to?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

This should already allow you to access `index.php` (the DirectoryIndex document) when accessing the main website URL (ie. `https://example.com`) because the regex `^([^\.]+)$` (note the `+` quantifier) does not match requests for the document root (the main website URL) - so the rule should not do anything and the request passes through, as if the rule did not exist.

Ordinarily, the only time this would fail is if the `DirectoryIndex index.php` is not properly set or the directive is being used in a *server* context (ie. not `.htaccess`). But you've demonstrated that `DirectoryIndex` must be set since this works OK when the directive is removed entirely. And if the `DirectoryIndex` was not properly set then you would get a 403 Forbidden, not a 404 as you appear to be getting. So, there would seem to be *something else* going on here.

If the request was somehow rewritten to `index.php` before the above directive is processed (although that does not happen on Apache - maybe it does on LiteSpeed?) then the regex (`RewriteRule` *pattern*) still does not match because the character class excludes dots (as in `<dot>php`). Although the preceding *condition* should already exclude any requests that map to a physical file.

On the other hand, a 404 is consistent with the request being incorrectly rewritten.

---

HOWEVER, this rule is not strictly correct since it rewrites the request (ie.  appends the `.php` extension) regardless of whether the target file (with a `.php` extension) exists or not. Any request that does not immediately map to a file is rewritten. This includes directories (and the document root is a directory).

Try the following instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite to append ".php" only if the corresponding ".php" file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

This now checks that the target `.php` file exists before rewriting the request.

The `DirectoryIndex` directive is just to make sure. But also removes any unnecessary `DirectoryIndex` documents that might be set in the server config.

Minor points:

- No need to backslash-escape the literal dot when used inside a character class since it carries no special meaning here.
- The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` was superfluous since the regex already matches both lower and uppercase letters.

Make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new rule above your current rule to check for an empty path (the root) and rewrite it to index.php like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use a tool like https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ to debug your `.htaccess` rules

Comment: Careful, this results in the `RewriteCond` only getting applied to that first, new rule! Hardly what you want!

Comment: This behaves similar to the original script I posted. When typing out the base URL I receive 404 Not Found error and have to explicitly type /index.php

Comment: @ArianTabriz I have tested this and it does work for me. Have you tested it with the tool I mentioned in the comment?

Comment: @DerLola I am not sure if that tool would work for me, I am testing in localhost

Comment: @ArianTabriz it is a tool to verify the .htaccess does what you want it to do, nothing else. But sure, testing it locally also works.

Comment: Manually rewriting the request to `index.php` should be unnecessary since this is the job of mod_dir's `DirectoryIndex`. And this must already be set correctly since it "works" when the directives are removed. So, this is really no different to the original directives in the question (which, at face value, should also "work").